# python map function does not work

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, map-function

This is the code I edit on an editor and compile on a shell.
If I enter the integer 19, when I print out c, it is still `['1','9']` instead of the `[1,9]` I want. I tried this on the interactive interpreter instead of compiling a python file and it worked.

```
a = raw_input("Please enter a positive number ")    
c = []    
c = list(a)    
map(int, c)
```

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reassign the `map` output to `c` as it is not in-place

```
>>> a=raw_input("Please enter a positive number ")    
Please enter a positive number 19
>>> c = list(a) 
>>> c = map(int,c) # use the list() function if you are using Py3
>>> c
[1, 9]
```

See the [docs on `map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

> Apply function to every item of iterable and ***return a list of the results***.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: This will only run in Python 2.7.X. In Python 3.X you will have to `list(map(...))` because `map` in Python 3.X returns a map-object instead of a list directly.

Comment: @ascenator This program will not run in Py3 only because of `map` but also because of `raw_input`! I will edit the tags on the original question. Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, right, I forgot about it. Of course input() is Python 3.X for raw_input() in Python 2.X and raw_input() therefore removed in 3.X. Tricky Python ;)

Comment: Yep. Anyway I'm up voting your comment to catch others attention :)